# WFS GetFeature with coordinates get response without geometry

Tags: geoserver, coordinates, wfs, getfeature

I'm working on a ReactJS project that used OpenLayers for displaying map. When app users are in map component, they can click on the specified address (coordinates) represent on the map and get the corresponding data(from MongoDB server)

Sample click event in app:
[image]

This is my WFS request URL to send to GeoServer: `http://localhost:3001/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=kict:v_plans_photo&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT (longitude, latitude))`

Here is the code for generating longitude and latitude (coordinates) to pass in `WFS request URL`
and handle map click event from users.

```
 handleMapClick(event) {
    // get current coordinates from user's click
    let centerCoords = ol.proj.transform(event.coordinate, 'EPSG:900913', 'EPSG:4326')
    
    // url with randomly hard-coding coordinates(this works)
    let url = "/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=kict:v_plans_photo&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT (128.9880585 37.7161098))"

   // this does not work 
   let url = `/geoserver/wfs?service=WFS&version=1.0.0&request=GetFeature&typeName=kict:v_plans_photo&srsName=EPSG:4326&maxFeatures=10000&format_options=callback:getJson&cql_filter=INTERSECTS(geom, POINT (${centerCoords[0]} ${centerCoords[1]})`

      if (url) {
        fetch(url, {
           method: 'GET',
           mode: 'no-cors',
        })
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(data => {
            let xml = new XMLParser().parseFromString(data)
            return xml
        }) 
        .then(       
          (response) => {
              console.log(JSON.stringify(response))

              if (response.children) {
                const popup = new ol.Overlay({
                  element: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this).querySelector('#popup')
                });
                popup.setPosition(event.coordinate);
                map.addOverlay(popup);
                this.setState({
                  content: this.renderContentsItem(response),
                });
                console.log(`this.state.content: ${JSON.stringify(this.state.content)}`)
              } else {
                this.onClose();
              }
          },
          (error) => {
            this.setState({
              isLoaded: true,
              error
            });
          }
        )
      }
  };
```

Is there any problem with the `coordinates`?

Comment: What values you code inserts as `(${centerCoords[0]} ${centerCoords[1]}`?

Comment: @user30184 value of `centerCoords` is generated based on the location that the user clicks on. The longitude usually starts with `127.` and latitude starts with `35.`

Comment: I'm not sure if the request=GetFeature shouldn't be GetFeatureInfo for the WMS service?

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: I'm not clear on what your problem is? does it not work or is it returning the wrong value?

Comment: @JesúsPinilla as I said above, I just tried hard-coding `coordinates = [128.9880585 37.7161098]`  and passed it to the URL with request=GetFeature and the response is correct

Comment: @IanTurton Sorry, I'm new to OpenLayers and weak in describing things in English. So I just want to say that I want to get response data from `GeoServer` using the above url with specified `coordinates` of location when user clicks on. But the coordinates I got seems wrong somewhere so that didn't work properly.

Comment: Because the not working query is fundamentally the same than the one with fixed coordinates that works I suppose that the values of centerCoords are just not passed on correctly.

Comment: @user30184 I just tried a request and the `centerCoords` returned `127.84515380859375, 35.25935688227547`

Comment: @user30184 I also get the same thoughts as yours but don't know how to fix that  coordinates issue yet.

Comment: I see a map with points, and a request that tries to do an intersection with another point? That would have to match exactly the position of a point in the database. Point intersection test would be fine against polygon data, but if your target is to locate a point, please create a small polygon instead, or do a bbox filter, around the position that the user clicked.